# How to determine the best 4 points from an list that make a rectangle?

Tags: python, list, coordinates, rectangles

After edge detection of an image, I have a list of point that make arbitrary shape, but i want to eliminate those that dont contribute to a rectangle shape. In the following example picture, the two points in the bottom left (E, F) should be removed, so the shape of the remaining points is almost a rect (since D is a little above, it give a trapezoid shape, but it is not significant)

I thought of brute force all points and compare their area, but it is not guarranteing of being a rect. But i dont know how to implement this in python.
If someone has a better approach i'd like to hear it please.
Thanks in advance.

[image: points f, e should be removed from list]

p = [ (8,133), (78,13), (242,89), (183,217), (217,235), (213,240) ]

Answer (score 0):

The best approach you can follow is using Slope

The mathematical formula for the slope of a given line is shown below.

```
m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

so for example: if the slope of (8,133),(78,13) is equal to (242,89),(183,217) this means we have 2 parallel lines, then we have a rectangle, but this doesn't mean that the 4 points on the 4 corners. however, they would be within 2 sides of a rectangle.

If you want to make sure they are on the 4 corners you can compute the slope of (8,133)(183,217) and the slope of (78,13)(242,89), then compare them, if they are equal, then you have 4 corners points of a rectangle.

backing to the code
first, you are going to need all possible combinations of length 4 of all the points, to accomplish this use `combinations` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import combinations

p = [(8,133), (78,13), (242,89), (183,217), (217,235), (213,240)]
possible_combinations = []
for comb in combinations(p, 4):
    possible_combinations.append(comb)
```

after that apply the above algorithm to each combination to get your rectangle.